# Haskell counting example

Tags: haskell

```
emptyAndOther
    :: IO (Int, Int)
emptyAndOther =
   do
     c <- getChar
     if c == '\ESC'
              then return (x, y)
     else if isSpace c
              then (x+1) y
     else x (y+1)
  where
     x = 0
     y = 0
```

What is wrong with this code?
I want to count every empty line and every char and on ESC button, return the result.

Dont seem to understand, what is wrong

yes, i must use this signature

Comment: Try pressing ESC in any text editor and see what character comes out...

Comment: Nothing, well that if c == '\ESC' should be right, but the rest of the code?

Comment: Correct observation, wrong conclusion. There is no character appearing because ESC doesn't generate any character at all, so of course there's no escape sequence for the character it generates. Is there an escape sequence for mouse clicks? Command line applications propably never see ESC and the like (at least they don't by default).

Comment: @delnan I'm not sure what you're getting at. I've just tried `ghc -e "interact show"` at the command line, and it prints `\ESC` characters just as expected.

Comment: @Daniel: Can't reproduce with Windows 7 `cmd.exe`, and I don't remember a ever using a text-only (no curses or anything) command line application that reacts on ESC. Perhaps some shells pass ESC one (but what character code would that be?).

Comment: @monadic: Clarified, I was talking about simple text-stream-based (`stdin`/`stdout`) programs, not curses-esque interfaces. Maybe both can, but I have only see the latter use them.

Comment: You don't want to do it that way in Haskell.  You need to separate the pure and impure parts.  So the part that reads and prints will be in IO, whereas the part that counts characters won't.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the fact that your `else` branches are attempting to call `x` as a function, which is a weird thing to do, since it's a number instead. I suggest trying to write a helper function

```
emptyAndOther' :: Int -> Int -> IO (Int, Int)
```

such that `emptyAndOther = emptyAndOther' 0 0`. For the future, I would point out that carefully reading error messages helps a lot. For example, GHC's error message says almost exactly what I did (though in terser language):

```
The function `x + 1' is applied to one argument,
but its type `Int' has none
In the expression: (x + 1) y
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a question in response.  In the code:

```
 else if isSpace c
          then (x+1) y
 else x (y+1)
```

What do the expressions `(x+1) y` and `x (y+1)` mean?  I'm guessing you're trying to increment x and y, but haskell doesn't work that way.

Instead, try having `emptyAndOther` take the current value of x and y, and then recurse in those two cases by calling `emptyAndOther (x+1) y` or `emptyAndOther x (y+1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function has return type `IO (Int,Int)`
Now lets see the 3 branches in  if/else

If part results in `return (x, y)` which is good as this will return a IO (Int,Int) and thats what your function return type is

Now in the `else if` and `else` part, the result seems to doesn't imply with the fact that your function return type is `IO (Int,Int)` .

Both the else if and else expressions should result in `IO (Int,Int)` type. This is just a hint. If you have worked in other programming language like C# and Java and try to write a function which return a string but in if part you return string and in else part you return int. That won't work .. same problem applies here